# Make two parameters optional but both required if atleast one is specified in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make a props type for a React component that can have certain fields but can
also have additionally two more fields. But they have to be both specified, or not specifed at all.

I was trying to achieve this with the following example:

```
interface Base {
    f: string;
    d: string;
}

interface ExtendedBase extends Base {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

const obj: Base | ExtendedBase = { // shouldn't this give an error that 'b' is missing?
    f: '',
    d: '',
    a: ''
}
```

I thought that with union it will require 2 Base fields or 4 ExtendedBase fields, but in the example above specifiying only 3 fields seems to satisfy the union, but why?

Any thoughts? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `obj` variable as you defined it can contain a `Base` or an `ExtendedBase` but the constraint when assigning it is actually "each property that is in one type **and** the other must exist in the assigned value".

The actual keys that must be in a value being assigned to `obj` are only `f` and `d`, and you can assign `{ f: '', d: '', a: '' }` because it has at least `f` and `d`.

If you want to keep this data structure, you could keep this solution and take advantage of the [type narrowing which is based on the control-flow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing):

```
interface Base {
    f: string;
    d: string;
}

interface ExtendedBase extends Base {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

const obj: Base | ExtendedBase = {
    f: '',
    d: '',
    a: '',
}

if(!('a' in obj)) {
    // obj is considered to be of type Base in this code block
    obj.a; // Property 'a' does not exist on type 'Base'.
    obj.b; // Property 'b' does not exist on type 'Base'.
    obj.d; // OK
    obj.f; // OK
} else {
    // obj is considered to be of type ExtendedBase in this code block
    obj.a; // OK
    obj.b; // OK
    obj.d; // OK
    obj.f; // OK
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to your type definitions, I would suggest making use of [Discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions). This way, you could refactor your code as:

```
interface Common {
    f: string;
    d: string;
}

interface Base extends Common {
    type: 'base'
}

interface ExtendedBase extends Common {
    type: 'extendedBase'
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

const obj: ExtendedBase | Base = { // gives an error that 'b' is missing
    type: 'extendedBase',
    f: '',
    d: '',
    a: '',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you can make use of *Type Aliases* 
For Example,

```
type MyType = {
  a?: true,
  b?: string
} | {
  a?: false,
  b?: string
}
```

Here, if `a` is `assigned/true` then b will be required, and if you wish not to assign or keep `a` as `false`, then `b` won't be required.

Hope this helps somehow! 
Good Luck :-D